# Average time series with missing time value

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy, time-series

I have two series date sets, as read into pandas like this (first column is row index, second is time and third is flux).

```
data1:
0  1977.262917  0.965209  
1  1977.283350  0.969835  
2  1977.303782  0.970732  
3  1977.365079  0.948716  
4  1977.405944  0.945410  

data2:
0  1977.262918  0.922487  
1  1977.283350  0.925750  
2  1977.303783  0.922952  
3  1977.365080  0.907151  
4  1977.385512  0.891967
```

I need to average the flux and time of these two data sets according to the time. However, as you can see, the time is not aligned. Some of them are missing. They are roughly separated by 0.02. I am thinking of re-sample all the time columns into uniformly separated ones based on the starting point. I want something Like this.

```
data1:
0  1977.262917  0.965209  
1  1977.282917  0.969835  
2  1977.302917  0.970732  
3  1977.322917  nan  
4  1977.342917  nan  
5  1977.362917  0.948716  
6  1977.382917  nan  
7  1977.402917  0.945410  


data2:
0  1977.262918  0.922487  
1  1977.282918  0.925750  
2  1977.302918  0.922952  
3  1977.322918  nan  
4  1977.342918  nan  
5  1977.362918  0.907151  
6  1977.382918  0.891967  
7  1977.402918  nan
```

And then fill the nan with the one after or before it. In this way I can directly average the two data sets since now they are roughly aligned. So how can I make this happen in python using either pandas or numpy, scipy etc. Or is there better method (other than the way I am thinking of) to achieve the job? Maybe an interpolation? Thanks guys.

Comment: I'd choose interpolation. There is a special scipy class for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you do that with [`interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html#pandas.DataFrame.interpolate) method with `method` parameter equals to `linear` to do linear interpolation or `nearest` if you'd like to fill gaps with the closes values for your resampled dataframe:

```
In [459]: df
Out[459]: 
             0         1
0  1977.262917  0.965209
1  1977.282917  0.969835
2  1977.302917  0.970732
3  1977.322917       NaN
4  1977.342917       NaN
5  1977.362917  0.948716
6  1977.382917       NaN
7  1977.402917  0.945410

In [460]: df.interpolate(method='linear')
Out[460]: 
             0         1
0  1977.262917  0.965209
1  1977.282917  0.969835
2  1977.302917  0.970732
3  1977.322917  0.963393
4  1977.342917  0.956055
5  1977.362917  0.948716
6  1977.382917  0.947063
7  1977.402917  0.945410

In [462]: df.interpolate(method='nearest')
Out[462]: 
             0         1
0  1977.262917  0.965209
1  1977.282917  0.969835
2  1977.302917  0.970732
3  1977.322917  0.970732
4  1977.342917  0.948716
5  1977.362917  0.948716
6  1977.382917  0.948716
7  1977.402917  0.945410
```

**EDIT**

For your resampling, `resample` method works only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex. So you could convert your column to `timedelta` then set it as index, resample, `reset_index` to get back to your original dataframe. Also you'll need to call `dt.total_seconds` to convert from minutes:seconds to only seconds as your original data:

```
In [575]: df
Out[575]: 
             0         1
0  1977.262917  0.965209
1  1977.283350  0.969835
2  1977.303782  0.970732
3  1977.365079  0.948716
4  1977.405944  0.945410

df1 = df.copy()
df1[0] = pd.to_timedelta(df1[0], unit='s')
df1 = df1.set_index(0)

In [582]: df1
Out[582]: 
                        1
0                        
00:32:57.262917  0.965209
00:32:57.283350  0.969835
00:32:57.303782  0.970732
00:32:57.365079  0.948716
00:32:57.405944  0.945410

In [583]: df1.resample('20L')
Out[583]: 
                        1
0                        
00:32:57.262917  0.965209
00:32:57.282917  0.969835
00:32:57.302917  0.970732
00:32:57.322917       NaN
00:32:57.342917       NaN
00:32:57.362917  0.948716
00:32:57.382917       NaN
00:32:57.402917  0.945410

df2 = df1.resample('20L').reset_index()
df2[0] = df2[0].dt.total_seconds()

In [593]: df2
Out[593]: 
             0         1
0  1977.262917  0.965209
1  1977.282917  0.969835
2  1977.302917  0.970732
3  1977.322917       NaN
4  1977.342917       NaN
5  1977.362917  0.948716
6  1977.382917       NaN
7  1977.402917  0.945410
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is something I want.

Comment: But do you know how to get from my original data set to the one with nans in it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could merge and then fill na's, for instance:

Load the data:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('df1',sep=' ',header=None)
df2 = pd.read_csv('df2',sep=' ',header=None)
df1.columns = df2.columns = ['time','flux']
```

Merge,sort,Forward-fill & calculate average:

```
full = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='time',how='outer').sort_values(by='time').fillna(method='ffill')
full['average'] = [(x+y)/2 for x,y in zip(full.flux_x,full.flux_y)]
```

[image: output]

Comment: I've been thinking the same thing as well. But I think if I do this, it's better do a rolling mean or median?

Comment: can't help you with that, it depends on your goals.